# Magento2 custom filter not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have added an attribute size as dropdown.
sizes are for example

24 * 24, 24 * 32

I have two products.

product1 -24 * 24

product2 - 24 * 32

storefront properties set as 
use in search - yes

visible in advanced search - No

comparable in frontend - No

Use in Layered navigation -filterable (with results) also tried (with no results)

Use in Search result navigation - yes

visible on catalog pages on storefront - yes.

used for sorting in product listing - no

Filters for other attributes are showing fine.

am I missing something?

Comment: Is your category set to Anchor ?

Comment: yes the Anchor is enabled.